# Compare value against parameters in Drools

Tags: java, drools

I am giving an object as an input in a Drools decision table.
This object has an "Amount" parameter.

What I would like to do is to compare this received value against a value present in a column in each row. How can I do that?

[image]

Basically, I want to compare the input.amount to the value on the same row in the right column.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot refer to a value that's given in a column to the right, but it's possible the other way round. Therefore, the columns should be written along these lines (assuming `Input` is the class name of the object containing the `amount`):

```
CONDITION      ACTION
Input
$amt:amount    insertLogical(new RoutingResult("$param"));
Avail.bal.
100            $amt
200            $amt
300            $amt
```

If you join the cells, you don't have to repeat `$amt` in each row.

Comment: And how should I proceed if I want to make a different comparison on each row in the Available balance column ? On each row, I want to compare the input.amount with an different number ( 100,200,..). I do not know how to write it in proper form.

Comment: If you look closely: there *are* different numbers in the condition column, so each rule will compare against a different value.

Comment: Thank you for your help. After solving this, I came into another problem. If you can look over this as well, I will greately appreciate it . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458990/how-to-call-a-java-function-in-drools