# send a mail from drools

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, drools-fusion

I'm create a project using Drools + Sprint boot.

I need trigger the mail when LHS satisfied. How can i trigger a mail from drl.

Let's say

```
 dialect "mvel"
  rule "mail trigger acoount hold customers"
   timer (cron: 0 0/30 * * * ?)
  when
        $customer: Customer( status == "hold") 
       then
        // send the account hold mail notification to customers registered mail address
  end
```

How can integrate the mail service with Drools.?

Suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a Java function in drools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458990/how-to-call-a-java-function-in-drools)

Comment: If the linked question by Augusto is not sufficient, please update your question with details about how you are attempting to call your mail function and what is going wrong when you do (eg if there are errors, please post the stack trace.)

Answer (score 1):

You could integrate Drools with Apache Camel: using Drools you define the rule for email sending, and Camel manages the actual email forwarding which can also properly manage potential SLAs with SMTP servers (for example via [throttling](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/throttle-eip.html)).

Your rule in this architecture would look ~like:

```
rule "mail trigger account hold customers"
timer (cron: 0 0/30 * * * ?)
when
    $customer: Customer( status == "hold") 
then
    // send the account hold mail notification to customers registered mail address
    Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    headers.put("To", $customer.getEMail());
    headers.put("From", new javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress("drools@kiegroup.org", "Drools"));
    headers.put("Subject", "Account hold mail notification");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("<html><body><h1>Account hold mail notification</h1>");
    sb.append("lorem ipsum");
    sb.append("</body></html>");

    try {
        camel.sendRouteBodyHeaders("direct:smtp", sb.toString(), headers);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO email was not sent
    }
end
```

and you would only need to manage the `camel.sendRouteBodyHeaders(..)` part to be properly configured based on your SB environment.
Additionally, `camel` could be a Drools global that is injected by Spring with the Camel's ProducerTemplate, this is really up to you.

This solution guarantees Drools is only used for the purpose of defining the business requirement when an email need to be sent, while the integration logic is performed by Apache Camel.

If you want to get more details, also for equivalent/analogous JavaEE or MicroProfile environment, some pointers might be found in [old post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/drools-usage/0BnuHBA8UiQ/lX-_8oBsPvcJ).

Comment: How is this not the same as the proposed duplicate? :-/

Comment: As I explained in my answer, once injecting a `camel` ProducerTemplate (it's a Camel interface, usually Camel bootstrap) this works by sending the email, it provides all the minimum reqs; the linked answer show a generic Java function which does not have anything to do with email

Comment: Basically the point is that Drools itself does not send emails. You need an external library (like Camel) to do that, which means you need to call a Java function from your rule. _That_ is why the other question is a duplicate, since it explains that you can call a Java function from the right hand side, and therefore invoke your complex logic (including sending emails by Camel or other side effects.)